# c has scanf, does python have something similar?

Tags: python, c

I am trying to solve problems from SPOJ. I need to be able to read input from stdin for that, I did a lot of problems in C using scanf but wanted to try Python as well. How do i read the stdin inputs in Python? (wanna use Python 2.6/2.7)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python 2.7

- To get integers or floats as inputs you can use the key word 'input'
  Example: temp=input("Give your value")
  Here temp only takes a float or int
- There is another command raw_input() any value that raw input is given it converts it to string and assigns the value
  Example:temp=raw_input("Give your value")
  Here temp is of string type

Answer (score 0):

For what I researched, in python 2.7(in all versions of python 2) the command of input is: raw_input( )

in this link have a tutorial about this:
https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-obtain-an-user-input-with-python-raw-input-function-example